# parenthetical units in regex returning extra matches

Tags: javascript, regex, parentheses

I'm new to regex and have been struggling with one, and have abstracted my problem to the following issue:

```
var foo = "abc";
var array1 = match(/abc/);
var array2 = match(/a(b)c/);
```

array1 will of course contain only "abc", but array2 will contain both "abc" and also "b".
Why does array2 pick up "b" as well?  This is a problem to me because I am matching some things inside braces like "{1 2a 3}", with a regex like `/\{(\d(|a|b)\s?)+\}/`, and the resulting array returns the empty string and "3" as well as the desired "{1 2a 3}".

Thank you!
Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(?:)` instead of `()`.

```
/{(?:\d(|a|b)\s?)+}/
```

When you use `()`, `match` return matched groups also. Groups are the part of the string that are correspondent to parts of the regular expression, which are in `()`.